# insert image to data with help of form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i am insert data of Django of model with image but image not insert

### model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True)
```

### form.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = '__all__'
```

### views.py

```
CreateProduct(request):
  context = {}


form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()

context['form'] = form
return render(request, "create_pro.html", context)
```

### html

```
<form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

{% endblock %}

### settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

Comment: Can you please rewrite the title to describe the problem? Right now it looks like you ask something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `request.FILES` to the form as well:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def create_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-view')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'create_pro.html', {'form': form})
```

In the form, you should probably also fix the spacing:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'name-of-create-product' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.

Comment: @alltypenews: it is, since you did not specify `blank=True` in the model. So if you do not submit a file, then it will not validate.